# Calculate width and height of AttributeText does not correct

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app chat and I have a problem with the chat message's size.

I've calculate my message's height like this and I've got the **correct height**

```
maximumMessageWidth = 300.0
let size = CGSize(width: maximumMessageWidth, height: 1000.0)
let messageAttributeText = messageBody.attributedText
let height = messageAttributeText?.boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil).height
```

To avoid the special case like this image. I have to calculate the width

[image]
It has the big space after my message

I want it to look like this:

[image]

This is the code I use to calculate the message width (I used the **correct height** which I've calculated the width)

```
let size = CGSize(width: 1000.0, height: height)
let messageAttributeText = messageBody.attributedText
var width = messageAttributeText?.boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil).width
```

but `width` in this code seem not right. Because I think it does care about my height property. **It assume that my text is in only 1 line**.
But I want to calculate the width, so that my text will `fill the whole label' just like the second image

Does anyone know how to calculate the width in my case ?

Comment: Use auto resizing from storyboard and you don't need to calculate size.

Comment: Actually, I don't use storyboard. Can you show me how to do it programmatically ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know programatically.

Comment: But I setting my messageBody by AutoLayout. I don't know if I can use Auto Resizing in this case or not ?

Comment: Sorry its autolayout. Just add your  storyboard. VC image

Comment: But I have to know 'width' and 'height' of message if I want to use Auto Layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139830/discussion-between-agent-stack-and-nguyn-anh-vit).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by casting `String to NSString`

```
var string = "Hello, World"
let nsString = string as NSString

let size = nsString.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)])
```

The size will give you `width` and `height` of the string.

You can apply this to your `NSAttributedString`s string property.

Comment: It just give me the size appropriate to draw my text.

Comment: @NguyễnAnhViệt you mean does what you expect?

Comment: @NguyễnAnhViệt i assume you need to set width & height of the label based on your `messageBody.attributedText`. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how to calculate the width if my text have more than 1 line

Comment: @NguyễnAnhViệt well by using above code you will get it. Have you tried?

Comment: I tried. And I get the width and height of the text in case everything is draw in 1 line. It do not know how many line I want to draw my text

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, I find out this:

The calculate width code doesn't work right because it do not care about the height property.

If `height = 100` or `height = 1000` it will return the same result because it assume to draw all the text in just one line.

So to calculate the width, I used binary search

```
var minWidth:CGFloat = 0.0
var maxWidth = maxWidth
while true {
    if (minWidth >= maxWidth) {
        width = minWidth
        break
    }

    let testWidth = (maxWidth + minWidth) / 2.0
    if calculateMessageHeight(width: testWidth) > messageHeight {
        minWidth = testWidth + 2.0
        continue
    } else {
        maxWidth = testWidth - 2.0
        continue
    }
```